# Greate number of rundll processes

Tags: windows, process

I have number of rundll32.exe processes opened in task manager.
Is there any way to find out which program is opening them or where they came from?

I have closed all my applications and they are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Open the task manager > View menu > select "command line"
Now you can see which process is launching the Rundll32.exe process.

Basically the Rundll32.exe is used by other processes to load a DLL.

Comment: Thanks.
I have CPU Usage 100%, because of number of rundll32.exe which is obviously used by: ..\AppData\Roaming\BABSOL~1\Shared\BUSOLU~1.DLL,EPUpdate Ret#SCH
This is what command line state for. Do you have any idea what this could be?

Comment: I'm afraid that you may have some malware infections. Googling this "AppData\Roaming\BABSOL" shows that it is related to an infection.